# Expected value for sum of iid normal variables squared

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_i$ be iid from a $N(\alpha, \alpha)$ distribution. I am trying to find $E[\sum_1^n X_i ^2]$ and thought that I would be able to transform the statistic $\sum_1^n X_i ^2$ into a chi-squared distribution as follows:

For $Z_i = \frac{X_i - \alpha}{\alpha ^\frac{1}{2}}$~$N(0,1)$, we have

$W = \sum_1^n Z_i ^2 = \sum_1^n [\frac{(X_i - \alpha)^2}{\alpha}]$~$\chi^2 (n)$

I was going to then find the expected value of this new W random variable. Is this a correct way to find the expected value of the statistic $\sum_1^n X_i ^2$ ? If it is not, or if there is a better way to find the expected value, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Z_i$ and $W$ aren't needed: you just need to note $\forall i, E(X_i^2)=\text{Var}(X_i)+E(X_i)^2=\alpha+\alpha^2$ and use the linearity of expectation to get:
$$
E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right]=\sum_{i=1}^nE(X_i^2)=n\alpha(1+\alpha).
$$
Note also that the independence assumption is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks! So, what you put is equivalent (though a much more efficient way) to finding the distribution of the statistic, then taking the integral of its pdf over the parameter space (like you usually would for a continuous random variable), correct?

Comment: @SKA Note that I was only aiming for the expected value of $\sum_iX_i^2$, not its distribution.

Comment: Okay - thanks for your help!